# Proving $(0,0)$ is a saddle point for $f(x,y)=2y^3-6y^2+3x^2y$

Tags: optimization, vector-analysis, maxima-minima, stationary-point

The function $f(x,y)=2y^3-6y^2+3x^2y$ has 2 stationary points, $(0,0)$ and $(0,2)$.
Using the function's Hessian I managed to prove that $(0,2)$ is a strict local minima, but the Hessian of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is $6\left({\begin{array}{cc}
 0&0\\0&-2
 \end{array} } \right)$ which is negative semi-definite, and by looking at the surface plot of the function + checking with WolframAlpha I'm pretty sure it's a saddle point and not a local maxima (although WolframAlpha did not classify it as a saddle point, but also not as a local maxima).

$f(0,0)=0$, and I did manage to prove that for $\epsilon>0$ the value $f(-\epsilon,-\epsilon)$ is negative.
I'm trying to find a combination of expressions using $\epsilon$ that when plugged into the function gives out a value which is always positive, so as to prove that each neighborhood of the point contains both positive and negative (smaller and larger) values.

I need help proving/disproving $(0,0)$ is a saddle point/local maxima.
Thanks!

Edit: fixed the function

Comment: Did you check whether, fxx*fyy - (fxy^2) < 0? fxx represents the partial derivative wrt to x twice, fyy for y, and fxy is once by x and y.

Comment: @SrinathPrasad i know that it is a saddle point if it's less than 0 but it works same if it's equal 0?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, less than. I had accidentally typed equal to. What did you get?

Comment: We got that the det at (0,0) is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said,
$$
f(x,x) = 5x^3 - 6 x^2
$$
is negative for $x$ small enough. On the other hand, for $y > 0$,
$$
f(\sqrt{2y},y) = 2 y^3
$$
is positive.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.